# C++ - sort algorithm doesnt see my overloaded "<" operator for user-defined type.

Tags: c++, algorithm, codeblocks

Ok so I have 1 user-defined type named `fraction` and it represents and ordinary fraction with a numerator and denominator. Here is the code:

```
class Fraction
{
private:
  int numerator;
  int denominator;

public:
  Fraction(int numer,int denom)
    :numerator(numer),denominator(denom){}

  int get_denom(){return denominator;}
  int get_numer(){return numerator;}
};
```

As you see it is completly implemented in a header file.

So what I want to do with this is sort a vector of fractions using the sort algorithm. Here is code of overloaded "<" operator (note: It is placed in same file as the Fraction class, but outside of the class):

```
bool operator<(Fraction& first,Fraction& second)
{
  if(first.get_denom() == second.get_denom())
  {
    return first.get_numer()<second.get_numer()?true:false;
  }
  int first_num=first.get_denom();
  int second_num=second.get_denom();
  int lcm=(first_num*second_num)/gcd(first_num,second_num);
  int first_new_numerator=(lcm/first_num)*first.get_numer();
  int second_new_numerator=(lcm/second_num)*second.get_numer();

  return first_new_numerator<second_new_numerator?true:false;
}
```

What it does is check if denominators are equal if they are then it tests the values of numerators. If they are not equal it equalizes them using least common multiple and gcd.

The real problem starts when I want to use the sort algorithm in main (compile time error).Here is the main code:

```
Fraction parse_fraction(string& input)
{

  stringstream fraction_string(input);
  int numer;
  fraction_string>>numer;
  char seperator;
  fraction_string>>seperator;
  int denom;
  fraction_string>>denom;

  return Fraction(numer,denom);
}


int main()
{
  vector<Fraction> fractions;
  string input;
  while(cin>>input)
  {
    if(input=="|") break;
    fractions.push_back(parse_fraction(input));
  }

  sort(fractions.begin(),fractions.end);

  for(int i=0;i<fractions.size();i++)
  {
    cout<<fractions[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Errors I get are (Note:I have properly overloaded "<<" operator for fractions but dont want to make clutter here):

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h||In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Fraction*, std::vector<Fraction> >, _Tp = Fraction]’:|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2253|70|instantiated from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Fraction*, std::vector<Fraction> >]’|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2284|54|instantiated from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Fraction*, std::vector<Fraction> >, _Size = long int]’|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5330|4|instantiated from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Fraction*, std::vector<Fraction> >]’|

/home/vanio/Desktop/workspace/C++/Ordner/main.cpp:35|43|instantiated from here|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h|2212|error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Fraction*, _Container = std::vector<Fraction>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Fraction&]() < __pivot’|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h|2212|note: candidates are:|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h|207|note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h|291|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h|341|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2510|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2522|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2534|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h|1290|note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)|

/home/vanio/Desktop/workspace/C++/Ordner/Fraction.h|39|note: bool operator<(Fraction&, Fraction&)|

/home/vanio/Desktop/workspace/C++/Ordner/Fraction.h|39|note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const Fraction’ to ‘Fraction&’|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h|2215|error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__pivot < __last.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Fraction*, _Container = std::vector<Fraction>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Fraction&]()’|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h|2215|note: candidates are:|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h|207|note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h|291|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h|341|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2510|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2522|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h|2534|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h|1290|note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)|

/home/vanio/Desktop/workspace/C++/Ordner/Fraction.h|39|note: bool operator<(Fraction&, Fraction&)|

/home/vanio/Desktop/workspace/C++/Ordner/Fraction.h|39|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Fraction’ to ‘Fraction&’|
||=== Build finished: 22 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: What happens if you make the operator a class member?
`bool operator < (Fraction & second)`

Comment: You should define the parameters to `operator<` as `const` references.

Comment: Two coding style suggestions. **First:** instead of `return a?true:false` just `return a`. **Second:** gcd is killing a fly with a cannon for this problem (and slow). Just multiply by both denominators. You can even skip checking if the denominators are equal, which probably costs more CPU cycles than it is worth.

Comment: There is no reason to use `...? true : false` in your `operator<` function.  The compiler should be able to convert the expression into a bool.  Leave it as `return first_new_numerator<second_new_numerator;`

Comment: It's opposite of the usual, but in this case the last error message is the important one.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Without using gcd, you can be in integer overflow land much earlier. Of course, multiplying first in the definition of `lcm` defeats the purpose. And using `int` to hold numerator and denominator isn't the best choice either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool operator<(Fraction& first,Fraction& second)
```

The problem is that your overload of `operator<` only accepts non-const arguments, but the algorithm is trying to compare a constant reference to a `Fraction` with the elements in your container.

Since `operator<` does not modify the contents of the compared objects, it should take them by const reference:

```
bool operator<(Fraction const & first,Fraction const & second)
```

Comment: A more common and readable version is: bool operator<(const Fraction& first, const Fraction& second);

Comment: @XanderTulip: Those are exact equivalents, and whether one is more readable than the other is up to discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
Fraction a, b;
bool res = (a < b);
```

The second line is essentially a call to

```
bool res = a.operator<(b);
```

1. As suggested above - being const correct is going to serve you very well in a long run
2. Define a member `bool operator<(const Fraction&) const` to make the sorting implementation happy or just go with the first suggestion above - be const-correct with `bool operator<(const Fraction& a, const Fraction& b)`

Comment: In this particular case, `operator<` is implemented as a free function, so the conversion would be `bool res = operator<( a, b );`. Additionally, it is more often than not, better to implement binary operators as free functions, rather than member functions, providing symmetry with respect to types (no conversions are allowed to call a member function)